# How to remove outliers from groups based on percentile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table `df` like this, but longer and with many other `type` values.

| type | weight |
| --- | --- |
| a | 35.1 |
| a | 36.7 |
| b | 100.2 |
| b | 99.3 |
| b | 102.0 |
| b | 5.0 |
| a | 38.2 |
| a | 250.8 |

I want to remove from `df` all records with outliers using the 95th percentile but broken down into individual values ​​in the `type` column.

For a single value of type, I do it like this:

```
my_perc = 95
temp = df[df['type'] == 'a']
temp[temp.weight < np.percentile(temp.weight, my_perc)]
```

Now I would like to do this automatically for the whole table `df`, taking into account individual groups in the `type` column.

I also tried this:

```
df[df.groupby(['type'])['weight'] < np.percentile(df.weight, my_perc)]
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, probably problem solved:

```
my_perc = 0.95
df[df.groupby('type')['weight'].transform(lambda x : x < x.quantile(my_perc))]
```

Comment: You got it, that's it. But you need  to pass value between 0 and 1 for `my_perc`, right now its `95`, instead make it `0.95`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.groupby` and group the dataframe on `type` then calculate the percentile using `np.percentile` for `weight` column for each of the group to get the required result:

```py
df.groupby('type')['weight'].apply(lambda x:x[x.le(np.percentile(x, 95))]).droplevel(axis=0, level=1).reset_index()
  type  weight
0    a    35.1
1    a    36.7
2    a    38.2
3    b   100.2
4    b    99.3
5    b     5.0
```

Comment: This answer in in the "low quality answers queue".